# Clicking on issue ellipsis link just shows a lightbulb, why?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

Clicking on the ellipsis link next to the issue, e.g.

[image: Catch Exception instead of Throwable. ...]

I get a little light-bulb icon with an x

[image: little light-bulb icon with an x]

in the lower right hand side of my window.  If I click on a link for duplicated code I get a similar x icon.  Why is this?  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a browser problem.  I [refreshed Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-preferences-fix-problems) and the lightbulb icon now expands to a window showing the correct information.  Refreshing Firefox also fixed a persistent "Still Working..." problem where no menus, etc. were available after I installed SonarQube on a new server.